# Is there any way to drag element from one grid into another in react-grid-layout?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-grid-layout

In my project I'm creating a UI Builder using NextJS and react-grid-layout and I need to give user an opportunity to make nested elements.

I have a page component which contains `<Grid></Grid>`, and `<GridBlock />` component which also contains `<Grid></Grid>`. I used `isDroppable` prop in `<Grid></Grid>`, so user can drag a draggable component from outside `<Grid></Grid>` and drop it into `<Grid></Grid>`. However, if there is a `<Grid></Grid>` inside `<Grid></Grid>` and user has dropped component inside one of them, he cannot drag it into another `<Grid></Grid>`. Is there any way to drag elements like that?